# Can we make 2 or more USB Internet Modems to work on one PC?

Tags: usb, 3g, 4g

I'm working on a project that require a working similar to connecting 2 or multiple USB Internet Modems to just one PC and make them work all together at the same time, and i want to know if i can use 2 USB Internet Modems in just one PC and make them work simultaneously.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Combing multiple internet or WAN connection is definitely possible, although there are lots of caveats. Google '3G Multihoming' to see some more background.

There are actually relatively cheap ($50 approx) routers which will support load balancing over multiple WAN ports - look for Dual WAN or Multi-homming in the tech specs.

You can also 'trick' windows into using more than one internet connection - see some links below.

However, unless you use a service on the server side also to help split the loads, you need to be aware of some limitations:

- If your use case has lots of requests that can run in parallel, as many web page downloads do, then this technique should work well.
- If you are downloading a single large file in one request then it will likely not make much difference, although if it is smart enough to move all other request to another connection it may help a little.

Some links for Windows dual connection use (note I have not tested these personally):

- http://www.wikihow.com/Combine-Two-Internet-Connections  (be wary of the 'double speed' comment)
- http://www.techkhoji.com/how-to-combine-multiple-internet-connections/ (see 'Method 2')